# mvc4 web api route sheme

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api-routing

I want access resource like this:

```
     /api/adddevice/12345
```

what is incorrect in this route?

```
    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "AddDevice",
            url: "adddevice/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "some controller", action = "adddevice", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );


    public string AddDevice(int id)
    {
        return "Device " + id.ToString() + " succesfully added";
    }
```

**EDIT**

Here is error details:

```
     <MessageDetail>
        No type was found that matches the controller named 'some controller'.
     </MessageDetail>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you want the url to be this:

```
/api/adddevice/12345
```

but your route mapping has this:

```
url: "adddevice/{id}",
```

See how it doesn't match? The mapping doesn't have `api/` at the start. The URL stated in the `MapRoute()` call has to match *all* of the URL (except the host part, of course). Either remove `/api/` from the URL you're typing, or add it to the URL you're mapping.

Incidentally, `routes.MapRoute()` is for MVC; for WebApi you want `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute()`.

Comment: I expect that mvc framework by default added [api] to separate api contrllers from usual - its surprize for me that action metod is not avaible when I append [api] to request url in this sheme:url: "adddevice/{id}"

Comment: I'm not sure why it's a surprise; the URLs simply don't match. They don't even have the same number of elements. You're typing something that starts with "api" and that route mapping is looking for something that starts with "adddevice". Simple enough. "api" != "adddevice".

Comment: I understand.this behavior is for sheme {controller}{action}...   /api/controller/action/44

Answer (score 1):

You missed out the 'api' in the route and you appear to be using MVC routing.

Note this needs to be added to the WebApiConfig and not the RouteConfig:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "AddDevice",
                routeTemplate: "api/adddevice/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "somecontroller", action = "adddevice", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

Comment: thats not work for me. .... here I am not use [api]  :      routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "PDF", action = "GetServiceInfo", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            ); and it works